# How can I iterate over a directory and identify or omit NTFS junctions (symlink-ish)

Tags: c++, boost, ntfs, poco-libraries, junction

I have some code to list the files in a directory. For Windows Systems, I'm hoping to end up with a list of files and folders that matches what you'd see in Windows Explorer. For example, when I list C:\ on Server 2016, I want to have the `Users` folder but not the `Documents and Settings` junction. Currently I'm getting both, with no apparent way of differentiating between them.

My current code looks like this:

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(dir);
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end;
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::JSON::Array> fileList(new Poco::JSON::Array);
for (; itr != end; ++itr) {
    boost::filesystem::path entryPath = itr->path();
    Poco::File file(entryPath.string());
    // ...
```

I tried the Poco `isLink()` method, but it returns false for junctions.

I also tried `Poco::DirectoryIterator`, which gives the same behavior as Boost, and `Poco::SortedDirectoryIterator`, which always throws `File access error: sharing violation: \pagefile.sys` when reading `C:\`.

Ideally, this code should include symlinks on Linux and MacOS systems, while ignoring junctions on Windows.

Comment: I think this might be what I need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa - I'll post an answer if I can get it working (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343643/933879)

Comment: Why do you not use the standard filesystem lib of C++17? There you might want to try this function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink.

Comment: Because symlinks are not quite the same thing as junctions - I'm admittedly a c++ noob, but I couldn't find anything in the std lib about junctions.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2012/12/09/using-ntfs-junctions-to-fix-application-compatibility-issues-on-64-bit-editions-of-windows/ has a bit more info about the difference between symlinks and junctions on Windows.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this without scanning and analyzing the entire drive. But you might want to take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/hard_link_count. But even with this function you can't differ between the original and the hardlink, you can only check if there is anywhere a hardlink to your path (at least in Linux hard_link_count is 2+the number of subdirectories+the number of hardlinks). I don't know if this might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I eventually came up with. It isn't a perfect solution - it's more of a heuristic than a proper identifier - but it seems to work well enough for my use case:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

bool FileController::isNtfsJunction(const std::string& dirPath) const {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        DWORD attrs = GetFileAttributesA(dirPath.c_str());
        if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == attrs) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            logger.error("Could not determine if path is NTFS Junction: %s. Error: %s", dirPath, err);
            return false;
        }
        return attrs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY &&
            attrs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT &&
            attrs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN &&
            attrs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM;
    #else
        return false;
    #endif
}
```